# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u012b' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, ascii

There is a text entry field (`Tkinter`), When I try to enter characters (ē, õ, ā),  it gives this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character `'\u012b'` in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

```
def layout():
    global msg_body1
    msg_label1=Label(f,text='Message+')
    msg_body1=Text(f,height=0,width=35,bd=3)

    global msg_body2
    msg_label2=Label(f,text='Message-')
    msg_body2=Text(f,height=0,width=35,bd=3)

    global msg_body3
    msg_label3=Label(f,text='Message-+')
    msg_body3=Text(f,height=0,width=35,bd=3)


def mail(): 
    try:
       server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
       server.starttls()
       a=send_email.get()
       b=send_pass.get()
       c=msg_body1.get('1.0',END)
       d=recv_email.get()
       server.login(a,b)
       server.sendmail(a,d,c)
       server.close()
```

Comment: Python 2 encodes most text input as ASCII, not Unicode or UTF. Characters like those can't be shown because they are not in the ASCII table.

Comment: Can you provide the traceback? Would help to narrow down whether the issue is in `tkinter` or elsewhere. Also, is this Python 2 or Python 3? The former is much less Unicode friendly than the latter (even when it works, it's sometimes value dependent, working for ASCII, exploding when actually handed non-ASCII data).